# Ignore case when comparing scala set equality

Tags: scala, set

How to compare two `Set` equality in Scala by ignoring case

```
   val a = Set("Test1","test2" ,"test3")  
   val b = Set("test1","test2" ,"Test3")
```

Comment: Can't you just write a custom equality check that ignores case?

Comment: was wondering if there any way to achieve this using scala collection library but did not find anything

Answer (score 3):

Just convert to lower case to do the comparison:

```
b.map(_.toLowerCase) == a.map(_.toLowerCase)
```